Extract XML-representation of MS Excel-Range
I am currently trying to efficiently save specific Excel files in a database in such a way that I can create a new file from different parts of my saved files.
Situation:
I have a lot of Excel files from which I want to store selected data in a database via a VB.Net-AddIn. Some of this data is easily stored since it is well structured (so basically I can store it with a type and the corresponding information). Additionally to the well structured data there are side calculations done below the corresponding rows, like this:
Row 1   : Some structured data I can store: Product type, Quantity, ...
Row 2-10: Unstructured side calculations e.g. calculation of quantities, can be done in any cell. Formatting is done in the whole row.
Approach:
My idea is to store the unstructured part as XML (with RC-formulas). In this way I can easily allocate it to the structured data from the first row and have the possibility to not only save it in the database but also read it back to create the same data/formulas in a new Excel file.
Problem:
I could go through all the cells read the formulas/formatting out and parse them one by one to an XML (similar to this but saving the formulas instead of only the values). But this seems to be very inefficient, especially considering that the formatting could go over the whole row. Excel is already saving all this information very efficiently as an XML-file. Is there any way to read out the XML-representation of a specific range or a more efficient way to parse it myself (without limiting the area in which the unstructured data/formulas are)?
I am not looking for finished solutions (well, if there is one I won't say no), but I have the feeling I am overlooking something or need input to untangle the knot in my head.
Thanks to everyone in advance!

xlsx files are actually .zip files full of XML that contains the data. You could try renaming the xlsx file to .zip, unzip it, and look around to see if your data is already in there in XML

Yes, you can read out the XML of a range with the Value parameter.
Dim r As Object   'r is a Range
r = ws.UsedRange  'assuming you already have a worksheet ref (set to ws)

Dim XMLRepresentation As String
XMLRepresentation = r.Value(11)

This will give you formulas, values, formats & everything about the range
